# Получить название монитора через WinApi

Tags: c#, winapi

В общем, хочу узнать модель монитора. Через WMI это не делается. Впервые столкнулся с WinApi и замер. Больше от недопонимания. [Вот здесь нашел код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279076/how-to-use-win32-getmonitorinfo-in-net-c), но не совсем понятно, как вставить его в проект). Не могли бы вы подсказать, как заюзать этот класс?

Comment: @mesteruh, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Без WinAPI, при условии что установлен драйвер на монитор.

```
using System.Management;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor"))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject currentObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            string monitormanufacturer = currentObj["MonitorManufacturer"].ToString();
            string name = currentObj["Name"].ToString();
            string deviceid = currentObj["DeviceID"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(monitormanufacturer + "\n" + name + "\n" + deviceid);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```